# How i can stop Youtube running Video in popup that i have popup?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, popupwindow

I have created popup window with the div tag when user click to watch specified video:

```
<div class="popup" >

                <h2 class="popup_header center">Tutorial - 2</h2>
                    <p class="popup_sub_header center"> Tutorial Label  </p>

                        <div class="popup_video_container">
                            <div class="video_frame pop_mode" id="popUpVideoWindow">

                                <iframe width="640" height="320"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" hspace="0" vspace="0"></iframe>

                            </div>
                            <div class="tutorial_description">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
            </div>
```

Now when i close this window video does not going to stop, continuing buffering and playing with other stuffs.
I have gone through other questions and found `afterClose`, `on('hidden')` method to work on `class` and `id`like this one:

```
$('.popUpVideoWindow').on('hidden',function(){

    $iframe = $(this)find("iframe");
    $iframe.attr("src", $iframe.attr("src"));

    console.log("Link set:" , $iframe.attr("src"));

});
```

and

```
$("#video_frame").bind('afterClose', function(){{

    $iframe = $(this)find("iframe");
    $iframe.attr("src", $iframe.attr("src"));

    console.log("Link set:" , $iframe.attr("src"));

});
```

but it doesnt going to help me what i want. I want to stop playing the video when i close that popup div.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var figure = $(".video");
    var vid = figure.find("video");

    [].forEach.call(figure, function (item,index) {
        item.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverVideo.bind(item,index), false);
        item.addEventListener('mouseout', hideVideo.bind(item,index), false);
    });

    function hoverVideo(index, e) {
        vid[index].play(); 
    }

    function hideVideo(index, e) {
        vid[index].pause(); 
    }
```

Check this example with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/0o8tt2z8/2/)

Make necessary changes.
check it please..regds

Comment: i have incorporate the youtube video with the help of <iframe> tag inside the <div>. So does it help when i use the id of div tag to stop the video. I have put close button on the popup window which links to main page

Comment: Just edited the code..Go through the jsfiddle..It will take little time to load video.plz wait..Reply me

Comment: i have gone through it. But cant find the proper solution from this one also. When i clicked on thumbnail of image it popup division containing video reference from (iframe) and several other parts (description and title of it). What i want when i closed it, it should reset src of that iframe video and stop the video from playing and buffering.